# PDF annotation tool

Tags: gratis, linux, pdf, pdf-viewer

I am interested in a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) local tool (e.g. a self-hosted web service running on Linux) which allows me to:

- Show PDF files in a local directory (a listing of those files and when I click on them, I want to see the PDF within the application)
- I want to be able to mark parts of the PDF. The location of those marks should be stored in an internal DB and the tool should be able to highlight the parts in the pdf dynamically. **It should NOT change the PDF itself**.
- It would be nice if the text in the marked region was automatically extracted, but that is not necessary. The label text will be supplied by the user.

[image]

Comment: Close, but no cigar: Xournal (available from your disto's repo) allows highlighs and annotations. Those are not merged into the PDF but saved into separate `*.xoj` files (basically XML with position and content). Doesn't really match your mockup, though – but who knows what ideas it raises and whether it might still be useful for you?